# Removing edges using vertex Labels in Igraph

Tags: r, graph, igraph, vertices, edges

I am pretty new to R. I have an igraph graph object and I labeled the vertices TRUE or FALSE randomly. Is there a way to delete edges which are between two TRUE-labeled vertices or two FALSE-labeled vertices?

Here's my code :

```
g <- read_graph("grph.graphml", format = c("graphml"))
num_of_edges <- gorder(g)
random_list <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), num_of_vertices, TRUE) 
V(g)$label <- random_list
```

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Make sure all terms like `num_of_vertices` and `g` are defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code refers to the file "grph.graphml" which we do not have, so I cannot use your example. Instead, I will use a random graph to illustrate.

```
## Generate random graph
library(igraph)
set.seed(1234)
g = erdos.renyi.game(15, 0.2)

## Your code to generate labels
random_list <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), gorder(g), TRUE) 
V(g)$label <- random_list
```

You can write a small function to test if the ends of an edge have the same labels and apply that to all edges. Then delete the ones where both ends are the same.

```
SameLabel = function(e) {
    V(g)[ends(g, e)[1]]$label == V(g)[ends(g, e)[2]]$label }
g2 = delete_edges(g, which(sapply(E(g), SameLabel)))
```

You can check that it is doing the right thing by plotting.

```
set.seed(1066)
LO = layout_with_fr(g)
par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(1,1,1,1))
plot(g, layout=LO, frame=TRUE)
plot(g2, layout=LO, frame=TRUE)
```

[image: reduced graph]

Some of these look wrong because links between distant nodes go behind other nodes of the opposite type.